# Извлечение сплайнов из модели класса GAM (`mgcv::gam`)

Tags: r

Прошу подсказать по следующему вопросу, который является продолжением [данного вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584541/how-to-extract-fitted-splines-from-a-gam-mgcvgam).
Строим аддитивную модель, как показано на примере из справки `?predict.gam`:

```
 library(mgcv)
 n <- 200
 sig <- 2
 dat <- gamSim(1,n=n,scale=sig)

 b <- gam(y ~ s(x0) + s(I(x1^2)) + s(x2) + offset(x3), data = dat)

 newd <- data.frame(x0=(0:30)/30, x1=(0:30)/30, x2=(0:30)/30, x3=(0:30)/30)

 Xp <- predict(b, newd, type="lpmatrix")

 ##################################################################
 ## The following shows how to use use an "lpmatrix" as a lookup 
 ## table for approximate prediction. The idea is to create 
 ## approximate prediction matrix rows by appropriate linear 
 ## interpolation of an existing prediction matrix. The additivity 
 ## of a GAM makes this possible. 
 ## There is no reason to ever do this in R, but the following 
 ## code provides a useful template for predicting from a fitted 
 ## gam *outside* R: all that is needed is the coefficient vector 
 ## and the prediction matrix. Use larger `Xp'/ smaller `dx' and/or 
 ## higher order interpolation for higher accuracy.  
 ###################################################################

 xn <- c(.341,.122,.476,.981) ## want prediction at these values
 x0 <- 1         ## intercept column
 dx <- 1/30      ## covariate spacing in `newd'
 for (j in 0:2) { ## loop through smooth terms
   cols <- 1+j*9 +1:9      ## relevant cols of Xp
   i <- floor(xn[j+1]*30)  ## find relevant rows of Xp
   w1 <- (xn[j+1]-i*dx)/dx ## interpolation weights
   ## find approx. predict matrix row portion, by interpolation
   x0 <- c(x0,Xp[i+2,cols]*w1 + Xp[i+1,cols]*(1-w1))
 }
 dim(x0)<-c(1,28) 
 fv <- x0%*%coef(b) + xn[4];fv    ## evaluate and add offset
 se <- sqrt(x0%*%b$Vp%*%t(x0));se ## get standard error
 ## compare to normal prediction
 predict(b,newdata=data.frame(x0=xn[1],x1=xn[2],
         x2=xn[3],x3=xn[4]),se=TRUE)
```

Возможно ли каким-то образом извлечь из модели в явном виде саму формулу сплайна `s(x)`, которая бы соответствовала форме записи:

yi = β<sub>0</sub> + β<sub>1</sub> b<sub>1</sub> (x<sub>i</sub>) + β<sub>2</sub> b<sub>2</sub> (x<sub>i</sub>) + · · · + β<sub>K+3</sub> b<sub>K+3</sub>(xi)

(James G. et al. - An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R)

Заметил, что путем умножения коэффициентов `coef(mod)` на `predict(mod, type="lpmatrix")` (матрица модели) можно получить предсказанные значения, возвращаемые функцией `predict(mod, type="response")`. Собственно, проблема в том, что я не могу поставить эти коэффициенты в соответствие степеням переменной `x` и `(x-knot)`, как это предполагается при записи сплайна в виде комбинации базисных функций. 
Приведенный пример предсказания значений на основе интерполяции значений из `"lpmatrix"` служит, согласно справке, для использования модели вне среды R. Означает ли это, что данная реализация GAM не предполагает получения записи модели в явном виде? Есть ли отличия в этом плане в функции `gam()` из пакета `gam`, написанного Хасти и Тибширани - создателями методам обобщенных аддитивных моделей?
Спасибо.

Comment: Литературы по этому вопросу не очень много, фактически только книжка Wood S.N. - Generalized Additive Models. An Introduction with R (для меня пока сложновато, разбирать всю математику нет мотивации, а в примерах на R этот вопрос тоже не рассматривают).

Comment: Возможно, вот то, что Вам нужно?
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5087/use-coefficients-of-thin-plate-regression-splines-in-a-clustering-method

Comment: Да, спасибо, вопрос на ту же тему, но аналитической формы записи сплайна там не получили. Сплайна там рисуют по точкам: `plot(Xp[,2:10] %*% coef(test$gam)[2:10], type = "l")`, где `Xp <- predict(test$gam, type = "lpmatrix")` - я об этом и писал. Предсказанные значения так получить можно, но как понять, где в матрице `Xp` наши иксы во всех степенях используемого полинома?

Comment: О том же спрашивают применительно к отдельному сплайну (не в составе GAM), и тоже нет ответа: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18077/getting-spline-coefficients-in-r?rq=1 (обсуждение закончилось на "but it does not give you any equations")

Comment: Похоже, нужно копать в эту сторону: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rms/docs/rmsOverview Focus is on regression splines instead of nonparametric smoothers or smoothing splines, so that explicit formulas for fit may be obtained for use outside S. rms can also compose S functions to evaluate X*Beta from the fitted model analytically, as well as compose SAS code to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В пакете `rms`, который является приложением к [известной книге](http://www.springer.com/gb/book/9780387952321) Ф. Харрелла, есть функция `Function()`, которая выдает уравнение поданной на нее модели. К сожалению, объекты класса `gam` эта функция не принимает. Но в состав `rms` входят другие функции, которые позволяют подгонять сплайн-модели - возможно, они подойдут и для Ваших целей. Примеры можно посмотреть [здесь](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67607/how-to-translate-the-output-from-an-lm-fit-with-a-cubic-spline-into-a-regressi) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28923695/coefficients-reported-with-restricted-cubic-splines-in-r-package-rms).